# Python | Request POST method in python 2.7

Tags: python, python-2.7, url, request

I am trying to connect to an API using `python 2.7`.

**Code:**

```
from urllib import urlencode
import urllib2

def http_post(url, data):
    post = urlencode(data)
    req = urllib2.Request(url, post)
    response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
    return response.read()
```

**Error:**

```
>>> r = http_post(LOGIN_URL, PARAMS)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in http_post
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 127, in urlopen
    return _opener.open(url, data, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 404, in open
    response = self._open(req, data)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 422, in _open
    '_open', req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 382, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1222, in https_open
    return self.do_open(httplib.HTTPSConnection, req)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/urllib2.py", line 1184, in do_open
    raise URLError(err)
urllib2.URLError: <urlopen error [Errno -5] No address associated with hostname
```

Similar code in `python 3.5` is running.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the url is not being found.

Have you defined LOGIN_URL just above the output we see in your "Error:" extract?